# Is there any way how to use/add/install my own Custom Query Module in Memgraph Cloud?

Tags: memgraphdb

On my local Memgraph instance (Memgrpah platform running in Docker) I've created a few Custom query modules. I'd like to use them at Memgraph Cloud. Can I add them to Cloud somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to do that. You can go to [Memgrpah repo](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph) and open an issue to request this feature.